# How to make complicated animation smoothly

Tags: graphics, manipulate, export, animation

I want to make animation smoothly. But when the function is complicated, manipulate cannot show animation smoothly. For example,

```
Manipulate[
DensityPlot[Sin[n x/y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> ControlActive[150, 150]], {n, 1, 10}
]
```

I want to .avi file of this animation smoothly. But when we change n, the graph is very rough. How should I export smoothly animation?

I use Mathematica 8.

Comment: Replace `Manipulate` with `Table` and generate a list of images, one for each frame. Then export the list using `Export["animation.avi", list]`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it. But how should I control the speed of playing the animation?

Comment: Look up "AVI" in the documentation and it will tell you that there is an option to `Export` called `FrameRate` that you can use to control that. The speed of the animation will be a result of the `FrameRate` and the number of frames.

Comment: Rather, the speed of the animation is determined by `FrameRate`. The *length* of the animation is the number of frames divided by `FrameRate`.

Comment: Do frame mean number of the table?

Comment: First of all it's time to upgrade your Mathematica!

Comment: I use Mathematica at my poor university. So we cannot upgrade.